# JSON decode to MySQL working on localhost but not Online Server

Tags: php, mysql, json, localhost

My code is as follows, I have changed the values of the Mysql login.

```
$json_url = "https://www.bitstamp.net/api/ticker/";
$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);
$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);

$bitstamp_btc_low = $json_feed->low;
$bitstamp_btc_high = $json_feed->high;
$bitstamp_btc_ask = $json_feed->ask;
$bitstamp_btc_volume = $json_feed->volume;

$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost",'username','password','database');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

    mysqli_query($connection,
                         "INSERT INTO `database` (Timestamp, Low, High, 
                                                  Ask, Volume)
                          VALUES ('$timestamp', '$bitstamp_btc_low', 
                                  '$bitstamp_btc_high', '$bitstamp_btc_ask',    
                                  '$bitstamp_btc_volume')");

mysqli_close($connection);
```

When I execute the code on my localhost server it works fine, inserts the data in to the database, in the format i require and its great.  When i upload it to my server though, it does not.  The only column it enters data into is the '$timestamp' column. (I have set an independent request for the date, away from the default Mysql entry.) So it makes me believe that this information is being received from the script.  Its just the low, high, ask and volume that is returning a 0 value.

I have contacted the API provider and they have confirmed that my host IP has not been black listed and all is well.

Im baffled as to why this is not working online, but it is offline, and just to confirm, even though its not entering the data into the cells, it is creating a new row just with 0 values.

**I have just run through the error log and i am getting these errors PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/wpdhcskl/public_html/cron-jobs/cron_bitstamp.php on line #**

**# being the lines with;**

```
$bitstamp_btc_low = $json_feed->low;
$bitstamp_btc_high = $json_feed->high;
$bitstamp_btc_ask = $json_feed->ask;
$bitstamp_btc_volume = $json_feed->volume;
```

Many thanks

Comment: what happens if you echo out the `$bitstamp_` variables ? do they contain data?

Comment: I have just run through the error log and i am getting these errors PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/wpdhcskl/public_html/cron-jobs/cron_bitstamp.php on line .

Comment: Yes each one contains data, it just seems strange that I cant get that data to display, I threw another script together just to echo it out and again, it works on my local server but not my online server

Comment: Try `json_decode($json_data, true);` to get the results as an array instead of an object, this will ensure you have strings only.

Comment: Fire, I have just tried that and i still get the same results. Nil value returned and still getting the error PHP Notice:    Trying to get property of non-object in the lines that represent $bitstamp_btc_low/high,ask and volume.  Im struggling to understand why this will work on my own computer but when i upload it to my server, it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a database called database? Okay....

Anyways try putting ` around the field names as sometimes different environmens have different setups...

```
INSERT INTO `database` (`Timestamp`, `Low`, `High`, `Ask`, `Volume`)
```

Also you should really escape your values and use something like PDO.

Comment: Hi, the actual database is not named database, its just renamed for this example, adding the ticks did not work unfortunately, Im baffled as it works fine on the localhost, but when it is uploaded i only get the timestamp entry and 0 figure for the other values